# FloatActionButton event click

Tags: android, xamarin.android, floating-action-button

I have an event click BotaoFlutuante_Click but not work to show message and to call my class (work fine to change set image). I don´t know what i´m doing wrong. Can help me?

```
private void BotaoFlutuante_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        botaoFlutuante.SetImageDrawable(GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.iconeverde));
        EnviaSms enviarSms = new EnviaSms();
        enviarSms.EnviarSms();
        Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "PAPAPAPAPA", ToastLength.Long);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "PAPAPAPAPA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You are missing the .show(); syntax and also change the ToastLength.Long into Toast.LENGTH_LONG

I once also spent hours working with that problem.

Comment: Can you mark this as the accepted answer so it can notify others who come across your question.